# How do i fix php my admin adding multiple line records as one record

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

So i was trying to add records to my database using php my admin like this:

```
data1
data2
data3
```

And since i ran into an issue where it says:

```
#1406 - Data too long for column 'data' at row 2
```

And realised that its trying to add all those lines ( one line = one new record ) as one line of data instead of making each line a record.

( I apologise for my lack of terminology I am fairly new to this )

here is my "data" column
[image: my "data" column]

its in varchar and should accept 255 characters max for each line

Comment: Your screenshot there is from the UI that allows to add _one_ new record. You will simply have to use this multiple times, if you want to create multiple records. Other options could be to import your data from a CSV file, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn the SQL language.

It should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (data) VALUES(data1),(data2),(data3);
```

In the phpMyAdmin interface add one entry per field. He doesn't understand what you want by separating the lines with a line break.